# ¿Qué significa el dicho mexicano, 'mete el hilo para sacar aguja' ?(en inglés, también?)

Tags: modismos

I was told it has something to do with being dishonest. I think it is something like "Contrary to popular belief".

Answer (score 1):

I have heard "meter aguja para sacar hilo" o "meter hilo para sacar hebra".

It means to start a conversation and hold it/twist it in some way to **indirectly** get information on a related topic.

Comment: Wow, I like that!! Thank you!!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You say a little lie to get a big truth

Comment: [to tell a lie, not say]